# AngularJS - ng-repeat, update a model object index which is not yet defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> I have a data object  **"data"** as below, but i need to iterate them
>   over the other array called **"values"**, and when I update the values
>   in view inputs, i need to update the model object "data" accordingly,

but the problem is index "b" is not defined in "data" object as inxdex "a" so how can i update "data" object in controller, for all the "values" array indexes including "b" which is not yet defined in "data" object.
**is there any alternative method for this kind of scenario?**

controller

```
$scope.values=["a","b"];
$scope.data={"a":{name:"A"}};

$scope.updateRate = function(val) {
   $scope.data[val]=//i want the input value here;
};
```

view

```
<tr ng-repeat="v in values">
    <td><input ng-model="data[v].name" type="text" ng-blur="updateRate(v)"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is the input value not updated properly into `data[v].name`, since that's what you've bound to `ngModel`? Otherwise, have you tried using `$event`? As in `updateRate($event, v)`

Comment: data[v] for index "b" is new to that model object, how can i set it? it's not going to automatically created right? when i type on the input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create all your key pairs in the controller before trying to set the model:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.values = ["a","b"];
    $scope.data = {};  
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.values.length;i++){
        $scope.data[$scope.values[i]] = {};
    }
    $scope.updateRate = function(val){
       $scope.data[val] = //not sure what your wanting to set it to here as the model is already the input value
    }
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j82mzfj9/

Comment: can't i push the new value to data object? so it'll be synced with view?

Comment: No the `ng-model` will create a new scope value for you but not dynamically for example you can do `ng-model="object.object.primitive"` and it will create it but you cannot do `ng-model="object[dynamicKey].primitive"`

Comment: I mean in the controller, because the data object is multidimensional huge array

Comment: Yes doing what I have done in my fiddle is setting up the model object for you, by default a controller and view work in sync when using `ng-model` so if you now edit an input value it will set `data['a'].name`

Comment: instead of initializing the data object for all the keys, why can't i just set the new value from the input when it changes, that way i  can initialize only if it's not initialized, because the data set is pretty big for pre-initialization

Comment: Yes you can check if it exists in the loop.... `if(!$scope.data[$scope.values[i]]) $scope.data[$scope.values[i]] = {}` I don't really understand your problem, but if your going to se a dynamic model iit has to exist on the scope....